# Appending element from this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im having issues making the code below to work. Basically, I wanted to move an element by appending to body on mouseover. whats wrong with my code?

Thanks

```
<div class="wrp">
<p>this is a wrap</p>
<p><img src="myimg.jpg" /></p>
</div>
<div class="wrp">
<p>this is a wrap2</p>
<p><img src="myimg.jpg" /></p>
</div>
<div class="wrp">
<p>this is a wrap3</p>
<p><img src="myimg.jpg" /></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".wrp").hover(function(){ 
$("img", this).appendTo("body");
});
</script>
```

expected output:

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
...
<img src="myimg.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does exactly that.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hCC2H/) is a jsfiddle where the images are broken of course but you can still see that it's doing what you want.

Comment: I think its because you moving `this` which is `.wrp` as well as the image, therefore you probably get the images moved to the body as well as the images, try `$(this).find('img').appendTo('body')`

Comment: @Val no that's not what `$('img', this)` means - it's the same as `$(this).find('img')`

Comment: Does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/YPmM7/1/

Comment: alright, I guess I have learned more here than @marvzz lol :)

Comment: hmm weird, ya i look at the demos and it's indeed working. maybe some error on my code.. ok thanks

Comment: I think you have probably missed the `<script>` tag for the jquery core itself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be handy if you showed us the output that actually happened. But that's besides the point...

Try doing the following instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.wrp > img').hover(function(){
$(this).appendTo('body');
});
</script>
```

I haven't tested it, it's off the top of my head. But it should work.